GitHub uploaded file output trouble
After uploading my project file in GitHub the entire output has been getting bigger when it's compared to VS Code Go-Live server. My every project file has been output has been changing. Why this has been happening?

Too little information. But it might have to do with linebreaks or text encoding.

You either have a size issue and/or an eol (end-of-line) issue.
You need to check:

your .gitignore, comparing it with a typical one for Bootstrap projects like this one.
The goal is to make sure you are not adding too much (like binairies) to your repository.
You can use git check-ignore -v -- a/file to check if a file is ignored or not.
your .gitattributes, like this one for the web (the certificate is expired on gitattributes.io, but it is still a good source for those files)

*.bash            text eol=lf
*.bat             text eol=crlf
*.cmd             text eol=crlf
*.coffee          text
*.css             text diff=css
*.htm             text diff=html
*.html            text diff=html
...

